# Como tirar a cor de fundo automática nos elementos em dispositivos móveis?

Tags: html, css

Bom, eu percebi que ao utilizar *Pseudo Classes* como `:hover`, `:focus` em elementos de entradas e em outros determinados elementos, para poder mudar do estado atual para outro estado difere de um navegador *desktop* para um navegador *mobile*, isso porque em um navegador *mobile* no caso do navegador *Google Chrome* para *Android* ele criar uma cor de fundo azul claro no elemento quando é tocado ou focado, enquanto em um navegador *desktop* isso não acontece.

**NOTA:** Nas imagens abaixo o botão é esse [Button Hover Effect Alternate](https://codepen.io/leandro-do-nascimento/pen/YzzbPPQ)
, ele está na minha conta do *codepen*, recomendo visualizar em uma versão *Desktop* e outra na versão *Mobile* para poder ver o comportamento.

**Exemplo**

**Exibindo em um Navegador Desktop (Google Chrome)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem acima quando o mouse é passado por cima do botão, não é exibido nenhuma cor de fundo azul.

**Exibindo em um Navegador Mobile (Google Chrome)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem acima quando há um toque no botão, é exibido uma cor de fundo azul.

Nas imagens acima mostram perfeitamente o que está acontecendo, eu não sei, porque isso acontece nos navegadores *mobile* e gostaria de saber o porque disso acontecer e se tem como remover isso, pois visualmente isso me incomoda, quem puder ajudar fico muito agradecido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso não é cor de fundo, é o realce (highlight) usado por celulares para auxiliar visualmente que aquele elemento é "clicável", botões e ancoras (`<a>`) tem isto (geralmente em iOS).

Para resolver provavelmente conseguirá aplicando esta regra no seu CSS:

```
html {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); /*pode ser transparent também*/
}
```

Não é um estilo padrão, não sei dizer se existe variações em Android e iOS, basicamente esta propriedade diz para o contexto (no caso apliquei ao `html` porque assim aplica a todos botões e afins, pode aplicar também somente a elementos isolados) especificado que o "tap" vai ter um "highlight" (destaque) com a cor `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` (que pode ser `transparent` também), sendo no `rgba` o último parâmetro a opacidade da cor.

O "ruim" de remover (deixar transparente) é que reduz a intuitividade do usuário, já que este é o propósito do "tap highlight", então no momento de criar os botões, links e afins procure aplicar algum efeito que lhe agrade e que ao mesmo tempo mantenha intuitivo que aquilo está "habilitado" e "clicável".

Comment: @MatheusATAR esse link que sugeriu não é fonte, eu conheço a tecnica a muito tempo, sou usuário de iPhone a anos, e desde a primeira vez que usei tive problema com o "tap hightlight", eu mesmo desenvolvi um FRAMEWORK proprio que usa isto: https://github.com/victory-css/victory.css/blob/master/dist/victory.css#L15 ... nem tem sentido postar "fonte" sendo que o texto da pergunta são palavras minhas e a resposta é apenas uma "propriedade css" e não uma técnica avançada.